# how to write a list objects in power query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I would like to create a list object to contain specific ID numbers ? How to write the code below more efficient ? many thanks in advance.

```
 #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "new col name", 
    each if [Col1] = "10011130" then "bla1" else if [Col1] = "10013030" then "bla1" 
    else if [Col1] = "10014030" then "bla1" else if [Col1] = "10015030" then "bla1" 
    else if Text.Contains([Col2], "bla2") then "bla2" 
    else "bla3")
```

what I tired

```
  #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "new col name", 
    each if [Col1] = {"10011130", "10013030", "10014030", "10015030"} then "bla1" 
    else if Text.Contains([Col2], "bla2") then "bla2" 
    else "bla3")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "new col name", 
    each if List.Contains({"10011130", "10013030", "10014030", "10015030"} ,[Col1] )  then "bla1" 
    else if Text.Contains([Col2], "bla2") then "bla2" 
    else "bla3")
```